# Laravel Passport: How do i get Access token from Bearer Token

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I requested client_credentials like below:

```
{
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "client_id": 8,
    "client_secret": "XXNKXXqJjfzG8XXSvXX1Q4pxxnkXmp8tT8TXXKXX",
    "redirect_uri": "",
    "scope": "*"
}
```

And then received response below:

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 31536000,
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGcXXXJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6ImEzYjJhZmU5OTYzMTE5MDAyZDAwZmEzNzU0ZGY3ZTRkMTgwYzhlYWRmNGQyOGU5MTI4YjAyYjJmYWQxZjY1NjUzMzAyZjNlZTI4MTgxMDFhIn0.eyJhdWQiOiI4IiwianRpIjoiYTNiMmFmZTk5NjMxMTkwMDJkMXXXYTM3XXXkZjdlNGQxODBjOGVhZGY0ZDI4ZTkxMjhiMDJiMmZhZDFmNjU2NTMzMDJmM2VlMjgxODEwMWEiLCJpYXQiOjE1NDAwMTQxNTUsIm5iZiI6MTU0MDAxNDE1NSwiZXhwIjoxNTcxNTUwMTU1LCJzdWIiOiIiLCJzY29wZXMiOltdfQ.sNSYywfBf27yAojqZclpjliysbQARlYFktzanTMecXXXIai5DgJY0sKhGpHktP5cqirYdemoFKy2nOxzZ8g29gCQQ63zmxe3vpbDz1GAdrjCDWoUlwSXXXHx4VIsdSIzVdi9XyvPKaLKMdoL6nFeWgpgXKGIvHKdiHjKgQbY_08Qa6JMN5Up27qmIOQoXJNAf1nuXvBMabUU_Js7VNspwPfdC8nMZ5zhK1A_c32_lDRtHqkhDfqqBXdUB-inx-zixhn2ODC4b4tkdj7XXXXlVKFxHxKM3aVOMFlmKhypSDwIUB0dPsN8iHcLzkl1yjzRQcOvQEj5BXWLkLCPdkiX2YJuFiWGUm_nxiYoIRV3ptJDeBI5OJI870JTOwBfJePrHTbXmhbjNSQSflLtiOV34wbPQZWH3KMKcsGVYvXXX3rcO5cbZWeeJLGPPYYO-_AWDmdAm-Qsb6Tw1sPxEZRw0dw3zBHnLVrEK9GXXXN2U5wE9Ka3id8ecOJSXSD39X1PyZUB9dJTidmbiWYWgskSTsqLuWfzXXXtlXkb1iOO37kT_Y5zr71Wp1RJ1Fp38yIyHI6fR9hKqeNALSqhv2ALmcSMQsFGTtPG98lGulu-vRJJhgMJ3C3fSTljN7o9BM7Jz-h0ymxC8sSMSNsXakK1qu40vD40zRJMB09sBPjIAVo"
}
```

In database, it will create record in `oauth_access_tokens` table, as follow:

```
id: 53ad95f4438e0f30769fa7e642e9c5b2fbd994fb3a95ece4a86578b07d2d72e61c01301df37e9bdb
user_id: NULL
client_id: 8
name: NULL
scopes: []
revoked: 0
created_at: 2021-11-05 09:30:14
updated_at: 2021-11-05 09:30:14
expires_at: 2021-11-05 09:30:14
```

Then I will use the `access_token` given above to consume my API by sending request Header as follow:

```
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGcXXXJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6ImEzYjJhZmU5OTYzMTE5MDAyZDAwZmEzNzU0ZGY3ZTRkMTgwYzhlYWRmNGQyOGU5MTI4YjAyYjJmYWQxZjY1NjUzMzAyZjNlZTI4MTgxMDFhIn0.eyJhdWQiOiI4IiwianRpIjoiYTNiMmFmZTk5NjMxMTkwMDJkMXXXYTM3XXXkZjdlNGQxODBjOGVhZGY0ZDI4ZTkxMjhiMDJiMmZhZDFmNjU2NTMzMDJmM2VlMjgxODEwMWEiLCJpYXQiOjE1NDAwMTQxNTUsIm5iZiI6MTU0MDAxNDE1NSwiZXhwIjoxNTcxNTUwMTU1LCJzdWIiOiIiLCJzY29wZXMiOltdfQ.sNSYywfBf27yAojqZclpjliysbQARlYFktzanTMecXXXIai5DgJY0sKhGpHktP5cqirYdemoFKy2nOxzZ8g29gCQQ63zmxe3vpbDz1GAdrjCDWoUlwSXXXHx4VIsdSIzVdi9XyvPKaLKMdoL6nFeWgpgXKGIvHKdiHjKgQbY_08Qa6JMN5Up27qmIOQoXJNAf1nuXvBMabUU_Js7VNspwPfdC8nMZ5zhK1A_c32_lDRtHqkhDfqqBXdUB-inx-zixhn2ODC4b4tkdj7XXXXlVKFxHxKM3aVOMFlmKhypSDwIUB0dPsN8iHcLzkl1yjzRQcOvQEj5BXWLkLCPdkiX2YJuFiWGUm_nxiYoIRV3ptJDeBI5OJI870JTOwBfJePrHTbXmhbjNSQSflLtiOV34wbPQZWH3KMKcsGVYvXXX3rcO5cbZWeeJLGPPYYO-_AWDmdAm-Qsb6Tw1sPxEZRw0dw3zBHnLVrEK9GXXXN2U5wE9Ka3id8ecOJSXSD39X1PyZUB9dJTidmbiWYWgskSTsqLuWfzXXXtlXkb1iOO37kT_Y5zr71Wp1RJ1Fp38yIyHI6fR9hKqeNALSqhv2ALmcSMQsFGTtPG98lGulu-vRJJhgMJ3C3fSTljN7o9BM7Jz-h0ymxC8sSMSNsXakK1qu40vD40zRJMB09sBPjIAVo
```

question: **how do I'm able to get `oauth_access_tokens` column `id` in my controller based on Bearer token given to my server?**

EX: how do I get this value in my controller:

```
53ad95f4438e0f30769fa7e642e9c5b2fbd994fb3a95ece4a86578b07d2d72e61c01301df37e9bdb
```

Based on Bearer token given below:

```
Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGcXXXJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6ImEzYjJhZmU5OTYzMTE5MDAyZDAwZmEzNzU0ZGY3ZTRkMTgwYzhlYWRmNGQyOGU5MTI4YjAyYjJmYWQxZjY1NjUzMzAyZjNlZTI4MTgxMDFhIn0.eyJhdWQiOiI4IiwianRpIjoiYTNiMmFmZTk5NjMxMTkwMDJkMXXXYTM3XXXkZjdlNGQxODBjOGVhZGY0ZDI4ZTkxMjhiMDJiMmZhZDFmNjU2NTMzMDJmM2VlMjgxODEwMWEiLCJpYXQiOjE1NDAwMTQxNTUsIm5iZiI6MTU0MDAxNDE1NSwiZXhwIjoxNTcxNTUwMTU1LCJzdWIiOiIiLCJzY29wZXMiOltdfQ.sNSYywfBf27yAojqZclpjliysbQARlYFktzanTMecXXXIai5DgJY0sKhGpHktP5cqirYdemoFKy2nOxzZ8g29gCQQ63zmxe3vpbDz1GAdrjCDWoUlwSXXXHx4VIsdSIzVdi9XyvPKaLKMdoL6nFeWgpgXKGIvHKdiHjKgQbY_08Qa6JMN5Up27qmIOQoXJNAf1nuXvBMabUU_Js7VNspwPfdC8nMZ5zhK1A_c32_lDRtHqkhDfqqBXdUB-inx-zixhn2ODC4b4tkdj7XXXXlVKFxHxKM3aVOMFlmKhypSDwIUB0dPsN8iHcLzkl1yjzRQcOvQEj5BXWLkLCPdkiX2YJuFiWGUm_nxiYoIRV3ptJDeBI5OJI870JTOwBfJePrHTbXmhbjNSQSflLtiOV34wbPQZWH3KMKcsGVYvXXX3rcO5cbZWeeJLGPPYYO-_AWDmdAm-Qsb6Tw1sPxEZRw0dw3zBHnLVrEK9GXXXN2U5wE9Ka3id8ecOJSXSD39X1PyZUB9dJTidmbiWYWgskSTsqLuWfzXXXtlXkb1iOO37kT_Y5zr71Wp1RJ1Fp38yIyHI6fR9hKqeNALSqhv2ALmcSMQsFGTtPG98lGulu-vRJJhgMJ3C3fSTljN7o9BM7Jz-h0ymxC8sSMSNsXakK1qu40vD40zRJMB09sBPjIAVo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*if you guys got any better solution let me know...

so far, this is how i kill it:

1. I Overriding `CheckClientCredentials` middleware:

   ```
   use Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckClientCredentials as Middleware;

   class CheckClientCredentials extends Middleware{

   public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$scopes){
       $psr = (new DiactorosFactory)->createRequest($request);

       try {
           $psr = $this->server->validateAuthenticatedRequest($psr);
       } catch (OAuthServerException $e) {
           throw new AuthenticationException;
       }

       $this->validateScopes($psr, $scopes);

       $request->attributes->set('oauth_access_token_id', $psr->getAttribute('oauth_access_token_id'));
       $request->attributes->set('oauth_client_id', $psr->getAttribute('oauth_client_id'));
       $request->attributes->set('oauth_user_id', $psr->getAttribute('oauth_user_id'));
       $request->attributes->set('oauth_scopes', $psr->getAttribute('oauth_scopes'));

       return $next($request);
   }
   ```

   }
2. access it in controller:

   ```
   dd($request->get('oauth_access_token_id'));
   ```

Answer (score 8):

To get the user by the token, you need to understand what the token is.

The token is broken up into three base64 encoded parts: the header, the payload, and the signature, separated by periods. In your case, since you're just wanting to find the user, you just need the header

To get the header, you can do something like this:

`$access_token = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGcXXXJSUzI......"`

```
// break up the string to extract only the token

$auth_header = explode(' ', $access_token);
$token = $auth_header[1];

// break up the token into its three respective parts
$token_parts = explode('.', $token);
$token_header = $token_parts[0];

// base64 decode to get a json string
$token_header_json = base64_decode($token_header);
// you'll get this with the provided token:



{"typ":"JWT","alg":"RS256","jti":"9fdb0dc4382f2833ce2d3993c670fafb5a7e7b88ada85f490abb90ac211802720a0fc7392c3f2e7c"}

// then convert the json to an array
$token_header_array = json_decode($token_header_json, true);
```

Once you have this, you can find the user's token in the jti key:

```
$user_token = $token_header_array['jti'];
```

I learnt this from @samsquanch

Comment: UPDATE: The current version of Passport places the JTI string value in the second token part, so:

`$token_parts[1]`

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel 8, perhaps others.

I created a middleware based on the logic of `League\OAuth2\Server\AuthorizationValidators\BearerTokenValidator`

I added it to `app/Http/Kernel.php` in the `api` section of `$middlewareGroups` so that it runs for every `api` route.

Here are the contents. I'm not discounting other solutions - this is just the route I decided to go so thought I'd volunteer the class.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Configuration;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Encoding\CannotDecodeContent;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Key\InMemory;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Rsa\Sha256;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Token\InvalidTokenStructure;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Token\UnsupportedHeaderFound;

class MergeOauthIntoRequestAttributes
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        // If authenticated and is an API endpoint and has the authorization header
        if($request->user() && $request->wantsJson() && $request->hasHeader('authorization')){

            $header = $request->header('authorization');

            $arrHdr = explode(' ', $header);
            if(count($arrHdr) >= 2){
                $jwt = $arrHdr[1];
            }else{
                $sErr = 'InjectOAuthDetailsIntoRequest - authorization header format not recognized.';
                logERR($sErr);
                $request->merge(['oauth'=>['s_error' => $sErr]]);
                return $next($request);
            }

            try {
                $jwtConfig = Configuration::forSymmetricSigner(
                    new Sha256(),
                    InMemory::plainText('')
                );

                // Attempt to parse the JWT
                $token = $jwtConfig->parser()->parse($jwt);

            } catch (CannotDecodeContent | InvalidTokenStructure | UnsupportedHeaderFound $exception) {
                logERR($exception->getMessage());
                $request->merge(['oauth'=>['s_error' => $exception->getMessage()]]);
                return $next($request);
            }

            $claims = $token->claims();
            $request->merge(['oauth'=>[
                'access_token_id' => $claims->get('jti')
                ,'client_id' => $this->convertSingleRecordAudToString($claims->get('aud'))
                ,'scopes' => $claims->get('scopes')
            ]]);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

    /**
     * Convert single record arrays into strings to ensure backwards compatibility between v4 and v3.x of lcobucci/jwt
     *
     * @param mixed $aud
     *
     * @return array|string
     */
    private function convertSingleRecordAudToString($aud)
    {
        return \is_array($aud) && \count($aud) === 1 ? $aud[0] : $aud;
    }

}
```

The calls to `logERR` can be deleted or replaced with your own logging mechanism.